# I am struggling with creating a random word rather than a string of words

Tags: java, macos, random

here is my code

i get a string of the words rather than just one, and i thought i had done it perfectly. if you could give me some pointers that would be fantastic, the only reason i included all the code is i may have over looked something, i think it has to do with the building of the phrase but i'm not sure

```
//import java libraries
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Emotion extends JFrame
{
    //set what you can use
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel phrasem;

    public Emotion()
    {
        setLayout( new FlowLayout());

        //Wordlists
        String[] wordlistone =
        {
                "anger","misery"+"sadness"+"happiness"+"joy"+"fear"+"anticipation"+"surprise"+"shame"+"envy"+"indignation"+"courage"+    "pride"+"love"+"confusion"+"hope"+"respect"+"caution"+"pain"
        };

        //number of words in each list
        int onelength = wordlistone.length;

        //random number
        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * onelength);


        //building phrase
        String phrase = wordlistone[rand1];

        // printing phrase

        phrasem = new JLabel("PhraseOMatic says:");
        add (phrasem);

        label = new JLabel("Today you emotion is: " + phrase);
        add (label);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Emotion gui = new Emotion();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(400, 100);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("My App (Alex Gadd)");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `+` where you should have `,` in the word list.
I think you just mistook the two there.

```
String[] wordlistone = {
    "anger", "misery", "sadness", "happiness", "joy", "fear", "anticipation",
    "surprise", "shame", "envy", "indignation", "courage", "pride", "love",
    "confusion", "hope", "respect", "caution", "pain"
};
```

---

Also, you can easily get random int with java.util.Random, it's better than `Math.random()`

```
Random rand = new Random();

int i = rand.nextInt(wordlistone.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

The plus "+" operator concatenates the strings resulting in just one word. Use comma as a word separator when you initialize the string array.

Answer (score 1):

Your word list array only has two elements. You used a comma between the first and second and then accidentally created a large string by concatenation with the rest of the words. Change this:

```
    String[] wordlistone =
    {
            "anger","misery"+"sadness"+"happiness"+"joy"+"fear"+"anticipation"+"surprise"+"shame"+"envy"+"indignation"+"courage"+    "pride"+"love"+"confusion"+"hope"+"respect"+"caution"+"pain"
    };
```

To this

```
    String[] wordlistone =
    {
            "anger", "misery", "sadness", "happiness", "joy", "fear", "anticipation", "surprise", "shame", "envy", "indignation", "courage", "pride", "love", "confusion", "hope", "respect", "caution", "pain"
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Two observations:

- Your `array` contains concatenated `String` values, so you should replace `+` with `,`
- You probably want to use a `Random` object here - `Math.random() * wordlistone.length` won't work

Here's my version:

```
String[] wordlistone = {
    "anger","misery","sadness","happiness","joy","fear","anticipation","surprise","shame","envy",
    "indignation","courage", "pride","love","confusion","hope","respect","caution","pain"           
};

Random r = new Random(); // you can reuse this - no need to initialize it every time
System.out.println(wordlistone[r.nextInt(wordlistone.length)]);
```